# Command substitution within sed expression

Tags: linux, bash, sed, substitution

I'm having little problem with bash/sed. I need to be able to use command substitution within sed expression. I have two big text files:

- first is logfile.txt which **sometimes*** shows error messages by ID (0xdeadbeef is common example) in format ERRORID:0xdeadbeef
- second errors.txt has error messages stored in pairs LONG_ERROR_DESCRIPTION, 0xdeadbeef

I was trying to use sed with bash command substitution to do the task:

```
cat logfile.txt | sed "s/ERRORID:\(0x[0-9a-f]*\)/ERROR:$(cat errors.txt |
    grep \1 | grep -o '^[A-Z_]*' )/g"
```

(^^^ this should be in one line of course)

If it would work then I could get little nicer version of logfile with better error info.

```
   Lot's of meaningless stuff ERRORID:0xdeadbeef and something else =>
=> Lot's of meaningless stuff ERROR:LONG_ERROR_DESCRIPTION and something else
```

But it doesn't. The problem is that sed is unable to "inject" regex section (\1) into command substitution. What are my other options? I know that it's possible to build sed expression first or do it other way but I would like to avoid parsing those files several times (they can be huge).

As always big thanks for any help.

*there is no real formatting inside logfile. No sections, columns, tab/coma-separation are used inconsistently

PS. Just to explain. Following expression works, but of course there is no argument passing within it:

```
echo "my cute cat" | sed "s/cat/$(echo dog)/g"
```

Comment: The design of `errors.txt` isn't exactly conducive to machine processing. Something like `0xdeadbeef Long description` would be easier to process. Maybe you'll want to generate a bunch of `#define`s from it on another fine day?

Comment: @tripleee - actually I have bunch of #define's terribly sliced with comments - and that's my real case. I was trying to limit this example as much as possible to not get into details. Important thing was just to have #define-like setup: TEXT 0xdeadbeef. That's why also your solution needs some tweaking on my side. I have to gather all header files and generate from them *.sed file. I'm working on this but your approach is as close as possible to something usable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a sed script from the error message catalog, then apply that sed script to the log file.

Basically, something along these lines:

```
sed 's/\(.*\), 0x\([0-9A-F]*\)$/s%ERRORID:0x\2%ERROR:\1%g/' errors.txt |
sed -f - logfile.txt
```

The output from the first sed script should be something like this:

```
s%ERRORID:0x00000001%ERROR:Out of memory%
s%ERRORID:0x00000002%ERROR:Stack overflow%
s%ERRORID:0x00000031%ERROR:values of beta may cause dom%
```

That is, a new sed script which specifies a substitution for each error code in the catalog.

There are different dialects of sed so this may require minor tweaking. The sed on Linux I believe should use backslash before grouping parentheses in regular expressions, and gladly tolerate standard input as the argument to the `-f` option. This is not portable to other Unices, though (but you could substitute Perl for sed if you need portability).

**Edit:* If the error messages are fairly static, and/or you want to read the log from standard input, save the generated script in a file;

```
# Do this once
sed 's/\(.*\), 0x\([0-9A-F]*\)$/s%ERRORID:0x\2%ERROR:\1%g/' errors.txt >errors.sed
# Use it many times
sed -f errors.sed logfile.txt
```

You could also add `#!/usr/bin/sed -f` at the top of `errors.sed` and `chmod +x` it to make it into a self-contained command script.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Problem with this example is that I would prefer get my logfile first - errors.txt is in file while logs are sometimes coming from pipe.

Comment: Then generate a static script in a file. I'll update with a snippet.

Comment: Amazing. Works like a charm. I've had to tweak it a little bit to match real life scenario (not this general example) and I was afraid that size of errors.txt will be a problem but it's faster than python or perl based approach. I need still to check how often errors.txt are updated and think if this solution will work for real. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this would work, since I can't get an answer on whether or not capture groups persist, but [there is a lot more to sed than just the `s` command](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Execution-Cycle). I was thinking you could use a capture group in a regex line selector, then use that for the command substitution. Something like this:

```
/ERRORID:\(0x[0-9a-f]*\)/  s/ERRORID:0x[0-9a-f]*/ERROR:$(grep \1 errors.txt | grep -o '^[A-Z_]*' )/
```

Anyway, if that doesn't work I would change gears and point out that this is really a good job for Perl. Here's how I would do it, which I think is much cleaner / easier to understand:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

while(<>) {
  while( /ERRORID:(0x[0-9a-f]*)/ ) {
    $name = system("grep $1 errors.txt | grep -o '^[A-Z_]*'");
    s/ERRORID:$1/ERROR:$name/g;
  }
  print;
}
```

Then execute:

```
./thatScript.pl logfile.txt
```

Comment: @tripleee Please elaborate (did you mean on the thatScript.pl call? Because yeah, I fixed that.

Comment: First example won't work. It's because that (as I suppose) command substitution takes place **first** - and this is also problem with my approach. Changing gears may be an option but I was hoping some pointers along awk or sth. similar. Perl may be fine for me but not necessarily in client env. Thanks anyway for nice perl snippet.

Comment: @tripleee Ah, I see what you mean now. Yes, grep is perfectly capable of opening the file itself.

Comment: @tripleee I don't agree with this kind of argument. Many times examples like this above are used with pipe. And it's easier to put some cat at the beginning so you can later just remove it and have working snippet. OTOH it's obvious that inside script some optimizing is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Just to let people looking for solution with bare shell and sed. Not perfect but working:

```
cat logfile.txt | while read line ; do id=$(echo -E "$line" | 
    grep "ERRORID:0x[0-9a-f]*" | grep -o "0x[0-9a-f]*" ) ; 
    if [ ! -z "$id" ] ; then echo -E "$line" | sed "s/$id/$(grep $id errors.txt | 
    grep -o '^[A-Z_]*' )/g" ;else echo -E "$line" ; fi ; done
```

If you see some fixing options then please share.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for gensub() and the 3rg arg to match():

```
$ awk '
    NR==FNR {
        map[$NF] = gensub(/,[^,]+$/,"",1)
        next
    }
    match($0,/(.*ERRORID:)(0x[[:xdigit:]]+)(.*)/,a) {
        $0 = a[1] (a[2] in map ? map[a[2]] : a[2]) a[3]
    }
1' errors.txt logfile.txt
Lot's of meaningless stuff ERRORID:LONG_ERROR_DESCRIPTION and something else =>
```

The above will run much faster than the sed scripts in the currently accepted answer and won't fail given various possible contents of `LONG_ERROR_DESCRIPTION` such as `%` or `&` or `\1`, nor will it fail when a given ERRORID is a subset of another, e.g. if `0xdead` and `0xdeadbeef` are 2 separate error codes then the sed scripts can fail depending on the order they appear in errors.txt, e.g. they could convert `ERRORS:0xdeadbeef` to `ERRORS:LONG_ERROR_DESCRIPTIONbeef`. by mapping `0xdead` first.