# how to use result from a pipe in the next sed command?

Tags: sed

I want to use sed to do this. I have 2 files:

```
keys.txt:
host1
host2

test.txt
host1 abc
host2 cdf
host3 abaasdf
```

I want to use sed to remove any lines in test.txt that contains the keyword in keys.txt. So the result of test.txt should be

```
host3 abaasdf
```

Can somebody show me how to do that with sed?

Thanks,

Comment: Roughly similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666149/command-substitution-within-sed-expression

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using `grep` for this (especially `fgrep` since there are no regexps involved), so

```
fgrep -v -f keys.txt test.txt
```

does it fine. With `sed` quickly this works:

```
sed -i.ORIGKEYS.txt ^-e 's_^_/_' -e 's_$_/d_' keys.txt
sed -f keys.txt test.txt
```

(This modifies the original `keys.txt` in place - with backup - to a sourceable sed script.)

Comment: if I do cat keys.txt | sed ... (remove this this key). How can I do that?

Comment: you just can't. sed is capable, but not that capable AFAIK.

Comment: At least with GNU sed it works by piping in the script, e.g.: `sed 's_^_/_; s_$_/d_' keys.txt | sed -f - test.txt`.

Comment: TIL about that option @Thor , thanks (but it's still not cat)

Answer (score 2):

`fgrep -v -f` is the best solution. Here are a couple of alternatives:

A combination of [`comm`](http://man.cx/comm) and [`join`](http://man.cx/join)

```
comm -13 <(join keys.txt test.txt) test.txt
```

or awk

```
awk 'NR==FNR {key[$1]; next} $1 in key {next} 1' keys.txt test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's|.*|/^&\\>/d|' keys.txt | sed -f - test.txt
```