# Sed command does not replace

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed

I'm stuck in getting my sed script work.
What I want to do is to find out matching word and replace.
However, in replacing, refer to intf.txt and take each line to replace each found item in order.

For example, I would like to replace "5/0/0" and "5/1/0" with "6/3/0" and "7/1/3".

Here is original input.
**$ more test.xml | grep --line-number physical_interface**

```
199:                  <physical_interface>5/0/0</physical_interface>
256:                  <physical_interface>5/1/0</physical_interface>
```

Here is the shell I wrote.
    **$ more replace-intf.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line;
do
        sed -e "s|[0-9]\/[0-9]\/[0-9]|$line|" ~/test.xml
done <intf.txt`
```

It takes "intf.txt" as input variable.

**$ more intf.txt**

```
6/3/0
7/1/3
```

I combine sed into while loop. 
So, I expect it will replace line by line with the contents in the intf.txt.

Here is the execution and output script.
    **$ more exec.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
./replace-intf.sh | sed -e '414,$d' > test1.xml
more test1.xml | grep --line-number physical_interface
```

Here is the result.

$ ./exec.sh

```
199:                  <physical_interface>6/3/0</physical_interface>
256:                  <physical_interface>6/3/0</physical_interface>
```

Now, my script only takes the first line of intf.txt.  It will never refer to second line which is 7/1/3 and does not replace 5/1/0.

Anyone know what would be wrong on my script?

Any comments are highly appreciated.

Comment: What's the relation between `replace-interface.sh` and `replace-intf.sh`?

Comment: There are many weird misunderstandings and unconventional constucts in your code. If you would make it less idiosyncratic, there would be less tangential gunk to sort out. Do you think you could reduce your question to just a single assumption of yours which appears to contradict what you actually see?

Comment: Also somewhat related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666149/command-substitution-within-sed-expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed` runs the substitution on all lines in the given file, not just the first one. So, in the first iteration of the loop, it replaces both physical interfaces with 6/3/0, and in the second one, it replaces both with 7/1/3.

Your next `sed` command removes everything from line 414 onwards. So, the second replacement obviously gets deleted.

But, you can use `sed` to generate a `sed` script that only changes the correct lines:

```
grep -n '[0-9]/[0-9]/[0-9]' test.xml \
| cut -f1 -d: \
| paste - intf.txt \
| sed 's%\t%s=\[0-9\]/\[0-9\]/\[0-9\]=%;s/$/=/' \
| sed -f- test.xml
```

The code generated by the first `sed` will be

```
199s=[0-9]/[0-9]/[0-9]=6/3/0=
256s=[0-9]/[0-9]/[0-9]=7/1/3=
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response!  It works!

What I don't understand is, after first 'sed' run, how appended portion is nicely deleted at second 'sed'?

For example, how is "199s=[0-9]/[0-9]/[0-9]=" processed at second 'sed'? Is it just ignored?  It is nicely deleted at second 'sed'.

Comment: Another question is, my system returns following error.

./replace-intf.sh: line 4: paste: command not found

I included #!/bin/sh or #!/bin/bash, but it did not help.
Is there any alternative way to do this instead of paste command?

Comment: `paste` is `/usr/bin/paste` on my system, it's part of `coreutils`.

Comment: Thanks.

Could you answer to my 1st question?  "199s=[0-9]/[0-9]/[0-9]=" portion is irrelevant with <physical_interface> tag.  It does not match.  How 2nd `sed' can pick 6/3/0 and 7/1/3 and replace nicely?

Comment: @K.K. `199` is the line number where to do the replacement.

Comment: Ah, you are using "=" as delimiter.  Now I understand what you mean.  Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @K.K.: Yes, `/` is taken by the string itself, `%` is used in the first `sed`, `=` in the second one.